# Why does not Firefox require a messaging server for Push notification

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I'm following the [Google PWA tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/pwa-integrating-push/index.html?index=..%2F..dev-pwa-training#3)

[image: tutorial]

then I saw this sentence. It just tells us no need for a messaging server for Firefox, but does not explain why and how to do it with Firefox.

So my question:
Why doesn't Firefox require creating a messaging server?
How do we do the push notification with Firefox without creating a messaging server/service?